# Too many connections Error due to many sleep connections

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, apache

PHP mysql_connect is sometimes failing due to "too many connections".
When checking the process status list, I am noticing that when this happens there are very long processes which are in sleep state. How long? time:28490

This is how I init the connection:

```
            $this->connection[$server] = mysql_connect( $credentials['dbUrl'], $credentials['dbUser'], $credentials['dbPass'], true);
```

This doesn't happen all the time, just sometimes that connections get 'stuck'. I assume it might have something to do with something on the page not finishing (image not loading? external service stuck?). When does a script officially finish? Is it after the page loads completely?

I've thought of two possible solutions:
 1. Using mysql_close. 
 2. Changing max mysql timeout (`/etc/my.cnf`)
 3. Handle script timeout.

What reasons can cause a connection to become stuck in 'sleep'?
How would you suggest to resolve / further investigate the issue?

Comment: Since it seems to be PHP, the connection should be released when the script completes, totally independent of images and other embedded content loading. If your php script hangs, the connection remains.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what can cause a php script to hang?

Comment: There are lots of reasons, usually a loop that never terminates, or waiting for some external thing to happen that never actually happens.

Comment: I assume apache max_execution_time should cover those reasons. Maybe I should look at why it's not configured properly?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution for this is to put your connection into a function, then add a destructor to close the connection for you. That way the connection automatically closes the after the last time the mysql connection is called.

```
class DbConn {
    public $connection;

    public function __construct($host, $name, $user, &$pass) {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        if(mysql_connect_errno) {
            echo mysql_connect_error;
        } else {
            mysql_select_db($name, $this->connection);
        }
        unset($pass); //Clear password for security.
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->connection);
    }
}
```

That should take care of most open connections as they will close before the end of script, even if the script hangs on an image, the connection will close after the last query is run. You'll probably still get a few, but not enough to cause a `too many connections` error.